# SQL Server : Case with function calls

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Table is:

```
+----+------+
| Id | Name |
+----+------+    
| 1  | aaa  |
| 1  | bbb  |
| 1  | ccc  |
| 1  | ddd  |
| 1  | eee  |
+----+------+
```

Required output:

```
+----+---------------------+
| Id |        abc          |
+----+---------------------+ 
|  1 | aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee |
+----+---------------------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    abc = STUFF((SELECT ',' + name 
                 FROM temp1 
                 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') 
FROM 
    temp1 
GROUP BY 
    id
```

This query is working properly. What I would like to do now is add a `case` statement in the select. If the XML is NULL, then display 'No names found', but SQL Server throws errors when I attempt to do this.

It either throws this error (see below) when used like this

```
SELECT
    ID, 
    abc = CASE 
             STUFF((SELECT ',' + name 
                    FROM temp1 
                    FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') IS NOT NULL 
             THEN abc
             ELSE 'No names found'
FROM 
    temp1 
GROUP BY 
    id
```

ERROR:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

or when used like this

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    CASE abc = STUFF((SELECT ',' + name 
                      FROM temp1 
                      FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') IS NOT NULL 
       THEN abc 
       ELSE 'No names found'
FROM 
    temp1 
GROUP BY 
    id
```

ERROR:

> Invalid column name abc

How can I add function calls to a `case` statements?

Comment: Your syntax on the CASE statement is incorrect. The CASE structure is `CASE <Test> <Action>` or `CASE <Value> <IsValue?> <Action>`. Your syntax is `CASE <Action> <Test> <Action>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template:

```
CASE WHEN test expression THEN resultant ELSE default value END
```

First pass

```
SELECT ID, 
    abc = CASE WHEN STUFF((SELECT ',' + name FROM temp1 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') IS NOT NULL
        THEN CASE WHEN STUFF((SELECT ',' + name FROM temp1 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
    ELSE 'No names found' END
FROM temp1 
GROUP BY id;
```

Use CTE to not have to put in big expression twice

```
WITH cte as (SELECT ID, 
        abc = ((SELECT ',' + name FROM temp1 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
    FROM temp1
    GROUP BY id)
SELECT ID,
    CASE WHEN abc IS NOT NULL THEN abc ELSE 'No names found' AS abc2
FROM cte;
```

In this specific case use `COALESCE`.

```
SELECT ID, 
    abc = COALESCE(STUFF((SELECT ',' + name FROM temp1 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
         , 'No names found')
FROM temp1 
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the CTE, never thought about going that route.  That seems like a good solution when `Coalesce` isn't a viable option.

Answer (score 2):

You can do :

```
SELECT ID, COALESCE(STUFF( (SELECT ',' + t1.name 
                            FROM temp1 t1
                            WHERE t1.id = t.id -- perhaps you need this
                            FOR XML PATH ('')
                           ), 1, 1, ''
                          ), 'No names found'
                   ) AS abc
FROM temp1 t
GROUP BY id;
```

However, i don't know how can you get `null` with preceding query with same table ?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use COALESCE Function Like this

```
 SELECT ID, 
   abc =  COALESCE( STUFF( (
             (SELECT ',' + name FROM temp1 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
           ) , 'No names found')
FROM temp1 GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

WHEN Keyword is missing in your query.

CASE WHEN expression THEN ... ELSE ... END

Comment: Correct...however there's also more going on here, you can't simply reference `abc` like that either after the `then` clause...

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
    ID, 
    abc = CASE 
             STUFF((SELECT ',' + name 
                    FROM temp1 
                    FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') IS NOT NULL 
             THEN STUFF((SELECT ',' + name 
                    FROM temp1 
                    FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
             ELSE 'No names found'
FROM 
    temp1 
GROUP BY 
    id

Answer (score 0):

You can just say

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT ',' + name 
                      FROM temp1 
                      FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''),'No names found') AS 'abc'
FROM 
    temp1 
GROUP BY 
    id
```

you don't need a case statement